# SimpleDateFormat - convert to other locale

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I define a format like following:

```
sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd\nEEEE, YYYY", Locale.getDefault())
```

Now I get exceptions on some devices like this one:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'Y'
```

So the problem is, the `Y` is not supported in this devices local. So I have to change the format to following:

```
// the string format is formatted in english, so we pass in Locale.ENGLISH
new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd\nEEEE, YYYY", Locale.ENGLISH)
```

**Question**

How can I now use this `SimpleDateFormat` to print a date in the locale language? I want that `EEEE` is german, english, spanish or whatever. So I need to use the english format string but then print the formatted string in local language. How can I do this?

**Example**

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd\nEEEE, YYYY", Locale.getDefault());
Date d = new Date();
String formatted = sdf.format(d);
```

*Expected*

```
DE: Juli 2017\nMittwoch, 2017
EN: July 2017\nWednesday, 2017
```

*Idea*

Create a `SimpleDateFormat` with the current local like `new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd\nEEEE, YYYY", Locale.getDefault());` but now I can't be sure that my string passed into the constructor is valid for the current locale... (Like the exception shows, `Y` is not valid in every locale)

Comment: How your input date looks like? Be carefull *Y* is week year *y* is year

Comment: Like `new Date()` or similar... Is that the question?

Comment: Add an [mcve] to your question

Comment: Done... My question is not about this, just about how to define the format in english, but print the result in any locale...

Comment: I believe the exception is Android-specific. The `SimpleDateFormat` class in my Java 8 cannot produce it. You may want to post a stacktrace so we have more information, and also give us some details about devices where the exception is seen.

Comment: If I feed January 1, *2017* into your format on my computer, it formats it into januar 01
søndag, *2016*. This is because capital `Y` is for week-based year, only useful with a week number — and January 1 happens to belong to the last week of the previous year. I think you want lowercase `yyyy` for calendar year instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix strings must be inside of sibgle quotes:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd'\n'EEEE',' yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
```

But `\n` is a newline. Hopefuly you want it there.

**UPDATE**

*(Like the exception shows, Y is not valid in every locale)*:
 Y is valid in every Locale!!

Comment: I want it there, yes. But how to I define the date format with an english pattern, but print it in any locale?

Comment: A pattern is not locale dependent. Only the Output is locale dependend

Comment: So the exception is caused by my missing quotes?

Comment: @prom85 Yes that's the reason. Also take care about upper and lower case char. Pattern are case sensitiv

Comment: Funny if this is true. [The documentation of `SimpleDateFormat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) only says to quote letters A through Z and a through z. “All other characters are not interpreted; they're simply copied into the output string during formatting …”. And as you say, `\n` is not a letter, it is a newline.

Comment: &@OleV.V. Not by simpledatefotmat by the shell of you print it out.